# Efficiently reading tokens from individual lines of file

Tags: c++, string, input, ifstream

I'm parsing a text file, reading a line at a time. For each line, I need to check to see if the first n letters match a particular word, then process the line.

Currently it is done such as this:

```
while (!inFile.eof()) 
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(inFile, line);            
    if (compareCaseInsensitive(line, "facet", 5)) 
    {               
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);   
        float a,b,c;
        std::string filler;
        lineStream >> filler >> filler >> a >> b >> c;  
    }
}
```

I'm reading the characters into a string, then copying those characters into a stringstream, then reading those characters out into the specific variables. This seems very inefficient. Is there anyway to read directly into the stringstream? or to extract the tokens from the string to prevent unnecessary copying?

Comment: It's unlikely that speeding up your code will have much effect - most of the time spent will be waiting for the disk.  (And that's probably still true even for an SSD.)  Try removing all the logic and just reading the lines - I bet it doesn't speed up by much.

Comment: Is the file small enough to fit into memory?

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize - this may _seem_ inefficient, but unless you have data to support that claim, you can't say for sure. The bottleneck will probably be disk I/O anyways.

Comment: How big are your files that you can actually measure a significant time spent on reading it?

Comment: @Mohammed, I swapped from using deprecated c functions to the STL code above and my loading times increased from less than a second to about 20 seconds.

Comment: @stefan, the file sizes range from 10's to 100's of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) is probably what you're looking for:

```
char filler[64];
float a,b,c;
sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s %s %f %f %f", filler, filler, &a, &b, &c);
```

However you'll have to fix the format string to take care of whatever separator you actually use, I'm just guessing here (spaces) for the sake of concreteness.  [C format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) give you a lot (though not unbounded) leeway for accounting for uncertainty in exactly how the input string is formatted.

Comment: Wow, I thought stringstream would be sufficiently fast, but I ran a small test and it actually turns out to be a lot slower. +1, although I personally dislike format stuff (more difficult to maintain, you have to modify two places, if type changed), it doesn't support custom types and I hate pointers.

Comment: @stefan Yes, these are drawbacks.  You can use `fread` for custom objects but granted that can get un-pretty as well.